# Variable number of reduce sums in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the situation:

```
token_ids = [17, 189, 981, 1000, 11, 42, 109, 26, 3377, 261]  
word_ids = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

where I need to compute the sum of `token_ids` reduced for each `word_id` like so:

```
output = [ (emb[17] + emb[189] + emb[981] + emb [1000]),  
           (emb[11] + emb[42] + emb[109]),
           (emb[26] + emb[3377] + emb[261]) ]
```

where `emb` is any embedding matrix.

I can write this code in python using for-loop like so:

```
prev = 0
sum_all = []
sum = 0
for i in range(len(word_ids)):
    if word_ids[i] == prev:
        sum += emb[token_ids[i]]
    else:
        sum_all += [sum]
        sum = emb[token_ids[i]]
        prev = word_ids[i]
    if i == len(word_ids):
        sum_all += [sum]
return sum_all
```

But I want to do it in **tensorflow** efficiently (vectorized if possible). Can anybody please give suggestions how to go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`tf.segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum) to computes the sum along segments of a tensor..

```py
import tensorflow as tf

token_ids = tf.constant([17, 189, 981, 1000, 11, 42, 109, 26, 3377, 261],tf.int32)
word_ids = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],tf.int32)

emb_matrix = tf.ones(shape=(4000,3))
emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_matrix, token_ids)

result = tf.segment_sum(emb,word_ids)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[[4. 4. 4.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]]
```